# Wrong output in php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting error that it can't read the value that already set before. I double check the value name and the database to make sure the value is same.

The code is

```
<form action='sendorder.php' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='productid' value='<?=$productid ?>'>
    <TR><TD><B>Product name:</B> </TD><TD><input readonly type=text name=productname value="<?=$_POST['productname']; ?>">
    <BR></TD></TR>
    <TR><TD><B>Price:</B> </TD><TD><input readonly type=text name=price value="<?=$_POST['price'].$curency;?>">
    <BR></TD></TR>
    <TR><TD><B>Stocks:</B> </TD><TD><input readonly type=text name=stock value="<?=$_POST['stock'];?>">
    <BR></TD></TR>
```

The output that came out is `<?=$_POST['productname']; ?>`

Comment: What is your question or issue you facing ?

Comment: ur php short tags are not enabled. change <? to <?php

Comment: `<?=$productid ?>` to `<?php echo $productid ?>` etc , replace `<?=` with `<?php echo`

Comment: @Rikesh My problem is that the output shouldn't came out as I state above, it should come out the product name that I set on other php file.

Comment: did you try out the different answers posted below?

Comment: @anurupr I did but turns out the output now become empty.

Comment: there are 4 variables in this context. are all 4 variables empty? if so, its definitely not getting set. and one more question, is it showing empty after submitting the form  or before?

Comment: @anurupr before submitting the form.

Comment: well ofcourse it would be empty before submitting the form. the `$_POST` variable won't be **set** at all until the form is submitted. are you setting the `$_POST` variable manually somewhere?

Comment: @anurupr I think you'e misunderstanding my problem here, but it's okay now. I tried to change some of the coding and now it works :)

Comment: well it would be great if you could elaborate on `I tried to change some of the coding and now it works` so in the future there would be a definitive answer to this problem that you are facing

Comment: @anurupr I change my <?=$_POST['productname']; ?> into <?=$_POST['productname']; ?> as recommend by michal.hubczyk

Comment: that was one of the answers shown before. interesting you didnt see that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php echo $_POST['productname']; ?>
```

instead of:

```
<?=$_POST['productname']; ?>
```

Or enable short_open_tag in php.ini

Comment: It's a configuration file of your PHP installation. I suggest further reading in the manual because it's good to know what are the basics of configuration.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably happening because short-tags are not enabled

Change it to

```
<?php echo $productid ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Might possible shorthanded tag not worked, `<?=`

try this `<?php $_POST['productname']; ?>` instead  `<?php $_POST['productname']; ?>`